# Storage permission restarts application

Tags: android, package, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-package-managers, runtime-permissions

I have a launcher application which runs on a custom firmware(have only Camera , Settings , Chrome & Explorer).

The problem come when we ask user (runtime permission) for `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on denying the permission `onRequestPermissionsResult` gets called but on allowing the permission application restarts.

This is not happening for `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` permission. I can't find any proper logs pointing to this issue. The same issue is happening for the above mentioned Camera application. So i have figured out it's something related to package dependency. Does anyone know what all packages are required for `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. If you want me to post the code, please do let me know. 
TIA