# Can i call grant permission ADB command from app

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am having an issue granting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` runtime permission in the app. On accepting the permission app is restarting, this I figured out is because of our custom firmware.

What I like to know is that, can we call ADB command for granting permission from the app. I've tried calling like this

```
final String STORAGE_PERMISSION_COMMAND = "sh -c adb -d shell pm grant com.example.easypermission.easypermissionsample android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
try {
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec(STORAGE_PERMISSION_COMMAND,null,null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But nothing is happening. Can someone tell me whether this can be done, if so how?

Comment: No it can't. Here is a small explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112381/3290339

Comment: @Onik It says i don't need to pass `adb` in the command. It doesn't say i can't run adb commands from app. Or that's what i understood. If i'm wrong, can you just explain it to me ?

Comment: you missed the key point in my answer... How can you run 'adb' commands without using 'adb' itself? This is a Linux binary, called 'adb' and the commands are it's arguments which are to be parsed by the binary. Using the command without 'adb' doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Onik oh okay. Thanks for the help. Can you look into this as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/55003244/5742437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link @Onik shared said, we can't run ADB commands inside app. When you run an app, its code is executed in the environment. So when you call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell command")` what you actually do is trying to start another  adb server process (on a target device now) which starts on tcp port 5038, since port 5037 is busy.

Comment: is there's a documentation that supports this answer ? anyway thanks @Shahal